# Host-based routing configuration in Symfony 2.2+

Tags: php, symfony

So I want to take advantage of Symfony's host-based routing.

Say I want to configure m.mydomain.com and mydomain.com - however I want the same app (Symfony app) to preside over both.

m.mydomain.com will be a different subdomain on the server. Basically, both of those domains will point to completely different locations. How can Symfony2 actually control both domains using ONE instance of the app? Or do I actually need to install one instance of the symfony app on each hostname supported? Do I need any .htaccess configuration to make this work specifically?

How does host-based routing really work?

Comment: Isn't [this documentation about hostname based routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html) helpful?

Comment: No. That doesn't answer my question at all. What I really want to know, is - do you have to install your Symfony2 app at the domain of each host you match? example - install symfony2 app at m.mydomain.com and mydomain.com both? So the route can actually be matched?

Comment: Both domains must point to the same location, the web/ dir

Comment: Is this possible with cPanel host

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on, you need to know about [virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting), a common feature in web servers such as Apache.

Given two or more host or DNS entries pointing to the same IP address, it is possible for a web browser to access the same web server via two or more hostnames (e.g. `m.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com`). When your browser requests a page using HTTP 1.1 (it's safe to assume this is the case), it will let the web server know which hostname it used to connect.

The web server can be configured to serve up a different website depending on the hostname - each website configuration is usually referred to as a virtual host.

It's also possible for a virtual host to serve up the same website (or web application) for multiple hostnames. An Apache configuration for this might look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias m.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain/web

    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

When Symfony processes the request, it has access to the hostname through the PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. It actually erases the superglobal arrays during startup, so you won't be able to use this within your application code. Call `getHost()` on an instance of the current request object instead.

Symfony's routing component uses this same information to filter requests by hostname. See the class `Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher`.

Hopefully with an understanding of what's going on, it should be possible to set up your web server so that the same virtual host is reachable via different hostnames, and then follow the Symfony docs [How to Match a Route Based on the Host](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html).